# Natural sorting in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Actually, I have a table in MySQL database. The table contains a column with alphanumeric data. I need to sort data in the column. A result which I would like to achieve is below.

```
1
2
2.B3
5
10 A-1
10 A-3
11
12
B3-43
B3-44
B3 - 48
BSomething 3
BSomething 4
BSomething 9
D.1
D.2
D.10
D.12
```

I have found some examples on the Internet about natural sorting in MySQL. I have written a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` ORDER BY  IF(name RLIKE '[[:digit:]]+',1,2), name
```

Unfortunately, it does not work in the right way. More precisely, it sorts numerical data as 1,10,2. I need a solution that will be good in every case.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `myTable` ORDER BY  CAST(name AS unsigned),LENGTH(name),name ASC             "This is not the exact answer but somewhat close to what you want now you can try and manipulate the query to get the desired ansqwer"

Answer (score 0):

try using **length()** function , if it don't work use **CAST()** ...

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` ORDER BY LENGTH(name) , name;
```

Comment: This would not give the exact answer as required

Comment: what about `DESC` order